# error in marque, the text dissappear and some times dont move completely CSS

Tags: css

I've created a marquee but its not full screen, its inside a card in the website. I tried to make it work like its infinite but it still cut and go away in an annoying way.
NOTE: the text is dynamic

```css
.card{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marquee {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
}
.marquee > * {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
}
.marquee > *::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<div class="marquee">
<p data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
<div class="marquee">
<p data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet consec">Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet consec</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the text to slide nicely without cutting infinitly just like the old marquee tag:

```css
marquee{
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<marquee scrollamount="30" height="">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, repellat?
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```css
/**
 * Core, likely what you want to copy/paste with little change
 */
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.marquee::before {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  /* Abusing `content` property and `attr` function to duplicate content in CSS */
  content: attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text) "        " attr(data-text);
  width: fit-content;
  transform: translate3d(-2%, 0, 0);
  will-change: transform;
}

/**
 * Only run animations when reduced motion is not set
 * Thanks @patrick_h_lauke@mastodon.social for the heads up!
 */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .marquee::before {
    animation: marquee 6s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .marquee--reverse::before {
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
    /**
     * -2% is used to start scrolling with an offset (visual only)
     */
        transform: translate3d(-2%, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
    /**
     * -2% offset has to be preserved
     *
     * Content is duplicated 20 times
     * 100% / 20 = 5 % = "1 content length"
     * 
     * -1px seems to prevent a small jump between each loop
     */
        transform: translate3d(calc(-2% - 5% - 1px), 0, 0);
    }
}

/**
 * From here, style marquee however you'd like
 */
.marquee {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 4vh, 3rem);
  flex: 1;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="marquee" data-text="lorem ipsum dolor ist as ment">
```

***REF***: https://codepen.io/lihbr/pen/poKKwEM